# How to differentiate between execution cases when using execvp?

Tags: c

When using excevp, how can I differentiate between the cases when the execution of the command fails and when the execution of the command ends with a non zero exit code?

Comment: Did you read the man-page?

Comment: "*when the execution of the command ends with a non zero exit code*" then the command got *exec*uted. So `execvp()` did succeed. If `execvp()` succeeded it does not return. The parent then needs to call `wait()` or `waitpid()` to gather the process' return code.

Answer (score 2):

If execution of the command fails (i.e. doesn't start) `execvp` will return -1 and `errno` will contain the relevant error code.

If the command is executed successfully, `execvp` does not return.  The parent process of the one that called `execvp` can call `wait` to get the return value of the command, whether it is zero or non zero.

Answer (score 0):

It's common to `_exit(127)` if exec fails and then have the parent interpret that exit code as an exec fail (shells, `system`, and `posix_spawn` all do this -- which effectively means they can't tell if the child did exec and returned 127 or if exec failed).

If you want a super robust solution, you could create a `O_CLOEXEC`-marked pipe before forking and then have the child process send the execv-elicited errno through that pipe to the parent.